# How to upload images via CKeditor 6.x - 1.3?

Tags: wysiwyg

is there any way to one click upload images with a CKeditor? Found this https://drupal.org/project/ocupload but sadly - its for 7.x version of Drupal :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce) it can be attached with a number of WYSIWYG editors like FCK Editor, CK Editor, Tiny MCE

Comment: Tried IMCE, but its hard for my site visitors i need a simple one click solution. Like some icon on ckeditor - when u press it → shows up a dialog screen to directly upload image from your pc to the server and paste it in CKEDITOR

Answer (score 0):

Can you upgrade to ckeditor-6.x-1.5. There you can use plugins for the CKeditor. One of the plugins is the IMCE button. This allowes you to skip the image dialog and upload a file. It still isn't a one click upload, but it's better than the normal IMCE upload.

Add the following line to your ckeditor.config.js
['Link','Image','IMCE'],

for the toolbar you are using.

Good luck